# Number of transitive relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

We have a set $A$ with cardinality $n$. How to find the number of transitive relations on $A$?

Also how do we get the following results?

Number of reflexive relations on $A=2^{n^2-n}$

Number of symmetric relations on $A=2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about a "transitive" relation other than from a set to itself.

Comment: Do you know that the number of binary relations on $A$ is $2^{n^2}$?

Comment: Yes, it is coming from number of subsets of $A \times A$

Comment: There is no general formula for the number of transitive relations.

Comment: @StubbornAtom That's unfortunate. Do you have any reference on that?

Comment: @Misakov I remember seeing a post probably here that the number of transitive relations do not follow a set pattern for varying $n$.

Comment: @Misakov https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579817/how-many-transitive-relations-on-a-set-of-n-elements.

Comment: Although the problem is still unsolved, progress has been made. In my paper, "On the number of transitive relations on a set", I have made some progress, I guess.(https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs13226-021-00100-0) [enter link description here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs13226-021-00100-0)

Answer (score 2):

We can think of binary relations as something like an ordered pair mapped to $\{0,1\}$. So, to fully characterize a binary relation, we just need to determine whether a certain pair $(a,b)$ is mapped to $0$ or $1$. That is why the number of all binary relations on set $A$ with cardinality $n$ is $2^{n^2}$. We first have $n^2$ ordered pairs, then there are $2^{n^2}$ mappings.

Following this thought, we can actually find the number of non-reflexive relations. There are $n$ pairs in form $(a,a)$, so there are only $n^2 - n$ pairs with distinct two elements. Those are the pairs we have to consider, resulting in $2^{n^2 - n}$ reflexive relations.

For the symmetric relations, consider it this way. Once we have determined $(a,b)$, we have determined $(b,a)$ as well. So we only need to work on $\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$ pairs. But hold on, we are forgetting $n$ pairs in form $(a,a)$. So we need to work on $\frac{n^2 - n}{2} + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ pairs, resulting in $2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ relations.

I haven't thought of a clever way of computing number of transitive relations yet but I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding the number of transitive relations on a set of ***n*** elements is non-trivial. The number of relations defined on the set itself grows exponentially (**$2^{n^2}$**)

For finding the other two, lets consider a matrix form of representing relations (assume rows & columns are ordered by the elements - where a ***1*** corresponds to ***existence*** of an element (ordered pair) & a ***0*** corresponds to ***non-existence***).
On a set n elements, the matrix is a square matrix with n rows & n columns (where each element corresponds to an ordered pair of elements from the set).
Make the following observations -

> All of the ***diagonal elements*** correspond to **Reflexive Relation**.
>
> The ***mirror elements*** across the diagonal correspond to **Symmetric Relation**.
>
> Total no of diagonal elements is **$n$**
>
> Total no of non-diagonal elements is **$n^2 - n$**
>
> Total no of mirror-element pairs is **$\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$**

Now, for a Relation to be Reflexive, all of the diagonal elements must be **1**, the other elements may or may not exist (either **0 or 1**).
In Symmetric Relations, all of the mirror elements occur in pairs i.e., either both **1** or both **0**, the diagonal elements may or may not exist (either **o or 1**).

Counting this way, its clear that the number of Reflexive relations is **$2^{\frac{n^2 - 2}{2}}$** and the number of Symmetric Relations is **$(2^n)(2^{\frac{n^2 - n}{2}})$** which is equal to **$2^{\frac{n^2 + n}{2}}$**