# Prove that $t_n>n(n+1)t_{n-1}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Despite several attempts, I have been unable to show that $$t_n>n(n+1)t_{n-1}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$ where $t_n$ denotes the number of transitive relations on a set with $n$ elements.

Would you try your hands at it?

Comment: How did this come up and what were the attempts? A lot is known on this, see e.g. [How many transitive relations on a set of n
elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/579817/152568), but it is unclear what methods you are expected to use.

Comment: It came up as an observation. The details lie here : https://oeis.org/A006905

Comment: If someone want to try, here's a hint. First look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252686/on-counting-transitive-relations for a bound that is *linear* in $n$. For a *quadratic* bound, a similar strategy might call for choosing *pairs* of elements from a transitive relation on $[n]$. Some observations on the *typical* shape of large transitive relations may then be useful, akin to Kleitman and Rothschild (1975), *Asymptotic enumeration of partial orders on a finite set*. There, that's a hint that may take you forward. I am not likely to spend more time on this now.